# How can i do this in c#

Tags: c#, loops

question updated: for clarification, sorry if my question is not clear.

here we go. what im trying to do here is change the tag name of a spefic tag based on its attribute, and delete the attribute

in this example i need to change Emphasis name with attribute italic to `i tag` name,
and para textbreak="no" to `p tag`

here is how i populate my listview

```
    //add data to listview
                this.lvContent.Items.Add(new MyItem { Tag = "Emphasis", Attribute = "Type", Value = "Italic", NewTag = "i" });
                this.lvContent.Items.Add(new MyItem { Tag = "Para", Attribute = "TextBreak", Value = "No", NewTag = "p" });


            foreach (MyItem item in lvContent.Items)
            {

                XElement rootI = XElement.Parse(txtInput.Text);
                IEnumerable<XElement> Emphasis =
                    from el in rootI.Descendants("" + item.Tag + "")
                    where (string)el.Attribute("" + item.Attribute + "") == "" + item.Value + ""
                    select el;

                foreach (XElement el in Emphasis)
                {
                    el.Name = "" + item.NewTag + "";
                }

                XElement xdoc = XElement.Parse(rootI.ToString());
                var elementsToRemove = from elemet in xdoc.Descendants(item.NewTag)
                                       where elemet.Attribute(item.Attribute).Value == item.Value
                                       select elemet;
                foreach (var ee in elementsToRemove)
                {
                    if (ee.Attribute(item.Attribute).Value == item.Value)
                    {
                        ee.RemoveAttributes();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
}
```

the output of the program

```
<Abstract>
  <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
  <Para TextBreak="No">Some paragraph <i>q</i></Para>
</Abstract>
<Abstract>
  <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
  <p>Some paragraph <Emphasis Type="Italic">q</Emphasis></p>
</Abstract>
```

and this is the correct output

```
<Abstract>
  <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
  <p>Some paragraph <i>q</i></p>
</Abstract>
```

the reason im asking how to `pass the output` of the first loop to the next loop is to

be used as `INPUT` to the next loop is because of the output.

i hope my question is clear now.

Comment: What do you mean by *data will be the output of the first loop* ? What do exactly want to do in each iteration ? At least write the expected output.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's really not clear what your specific problem is. Read data from the textbox? Write to the textbox?

Comment: i already updated the question and the possible output. thank you. and im sorry im not  good in english

Comment: I think you should use string.Replace or Regex replace....

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = "some text";
string[] pets = { "dog", "cat", "bird" };
input += " ";

foreach (string value in pets)
{
   input += " " + value;
}

Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Or a simpler one-liner for precise case could be:

```
Console.WriteLine(input + " " + String.Join(" ", pets));
```

Comment: Well, Congrats for appending my answer to this post, anyway the first option with lots of  `+=` will not be a good solution when compared to the second.

Comment: Just as an addition for this answer: I recommend using a [StringBuilder](https://www.google.de/search?q=C%23+stringbuilder&gws_rd=cr&ei=ABSPV4LoB4regAbDxomYBA) for string manipulation.

Comment: i already updated the question with the problem i am facing. i hope the question is clear now

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, make a new variable above the loop, then save to it in the end of the loop like this:

```
string input = "some text";
string[] pets = { "dog", "cat", "bird" };
string manipulateddata;

foreach (string value in pets)
{
    manipulateddata = ;//whatever your loop should do (you can use manipulated data here to manipulate)
}
Console.Writeline(manipulateddata);
```

Comment: i already updated the question with the problem i am facing. i hope the question is clear now

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this without looping:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}",input ,String.Join(" ",pets));
```

[Here is working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7PMhNe)

The following code will help you to correct your mistake, I wont suggest you to follow `+=` instead for that use `StringBuilder` like this:

```
    string input = "some text";
    string[] pets = { "dog", "cat", "bird" };
    StringBuilder outputBuilder= new StringBuilder(input);
    foreach(string pet in pets)
    {
        outputBuilder.Append(" ");
        outputBuilder.Append(pet);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}",outputBuilder.ToString());
```

[Example with StringBuilder](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wC5J7N)

Comment: i already updated the question with the problem i am facing. i hope the question is clear now

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **String.Join** to achieve your expected output. Like..

```
Console.WriteLine(input + String.Join(" ", pets));
```

Hope this helps!